Unable to import module lambda_function: no module named confluent_kafka.cimpl while creating a lambda layer
I am doing the following to bundle a layer with lambda, i need the confluent-kafka library to run inside the lambda function:
docker pull amazonlinux 
docker run -it amazonlinux 

yum install -y python39 zip unzip 

curl -O https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py 

python3 get-pip.py --user

export PATH=$HOME/.local/bin:$PATH

pip --version

mkdir python 

pip3 install confluent_kafka -t python
pip3 install requests -t python

zip -r /python/python.zip /python

exit from bash 

docker container ls --all

mkdir python

docker cp {docker_image_name}:/python/python.zip python/ 


The requests module is being imported correctly but the confluent kafka is not getting imported as expected with the error message:
"errorMessage": "Unable to import module 'lambda_function': No module named 'confluent_kafka.cimpl'",
